# Mongo DB - adding or removing from nested arrays

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongomapper

In Mongo, each of document of my collection is structured like below

```
    {
        id:"some id",
        name: "some name",
        nestedArray:[{nested-id: "some-id", value="some-value", status:"1"}, 
{nested-id: "some-id", value="some-value1", status:"2"}]
    }
```

Now, I have a couple of requirements. Wondering if the below update actions can be done in a single update query (or one atomic operation)

1) Retrieve some records in the above collection based on a query and remove some objects from nestedArray across all matching documents.

2) Retrieve some records in the above collection based a query and add a new object to the nestedArray for those records across all matching documents

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question on Mongo documentation. I would have to use the $push and $pull operators along with the update query - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/